# Bundler error on Heroku (with capybara gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have rails app and locally everything works (server starts etc.)
But when I wont to run my app on heroku I have problem (when I type `git push heroku master`:

> remote:        Installing capybara 2.4.4 remote:         remote:
>   Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>   remote:         remote:
>   /tmp/build_e1c43ae12e0eb81663efdbfcf4917456/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb remote:        *** extconf.rb failed *** remote:
>   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
>   necessary remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log
>   file for more details.  You may remote:        need configuration
>   options. remote:         remote:        Provided configuration
>   options: remote:        --with-opt-dir remote:
>   --without-opt-dir remote:        --with-opt-include remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include remote:        --with-opt-lib remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib remote:
>   --with-make-prog remote:        --without-make-prog remote:        --srcdir=. remote:        --curdir remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_e1c43ae12e0eb81663efdbfcf4917456/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby
>   remote:        --with-gl-dir remote:        --without-gl-dir remote:
>   --with-gl-include remote:        --without-gl-include=${gl-dir}/include remote:        --with-gl-lib remote:        --without-gl-lib=${gl-dir}/lib remote:
>   --with-zlib-dir remote:        --without-zlib-dir remote:        --with-zlib-include remote:        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include remote:        --with-zlib-lib remote:        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib remote:        Command 'qmake ' not available remote:         remote: 
>   extconf failed, exit code 1 remote:         remote:        Gem files
>   will remain installed in
>   /tmp/build_e1c43ae12e0eb81663efdbfcf4917456/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/capybara-webkit-1.6.0
>   for inspection. remote:        Results logged to
>   /tmp/build_e1c43ae12e0eb81663efdbfcf4917456/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/capybara-webkit-1.6.0/gem_make.out
>   remote:        An error occurred while installing capybara-webkit
>   (1.6.0), and Bundler cannot remote:        continue. remote:
>   Make sure that `gem install capybara-webkit -v '1.6.0'` succeeds
>   before remote:        bundling. remote:  ! remote:  !     Failed to
>   install gems via Bundler. remote:  ! remote:  remote:  !     Push
>   rejected, failed to compile Ruby app remote:  remote: Verifying
>   deploy.... remote:  remote: ! Push rejected to foosballtr. remote:  To
>   https://git.heroku.com/foosballtr.git  ! [remote rejected] master ->
>   master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://git.heroku.com/foosballtr.git'

And this is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.1.5'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'sprockets'
gem 'capybara-webkit'
gem "chartkick"

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

group :development, :test do  
  gem 'guard-rspec'  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'  
  # gem 'pry-rails'  
  gem 'rspec-rails'  
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'  
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Move `gem 'capybara-webkit'` to the `:development, :test` group, it's no need in production:

> Many apps depend on gems with native extensions that need to be
>   compiled on the deployment target.

[`Ref`](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/3/10/gem_manifests)

```
group :development, :test do  
  gem 'guard-rspec'  
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'  
  # gem 'pry-rails'  
  gem 'rspec-rails'  
  gem 'capybara-webkit'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'capybara'  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change with this in your gem file:

```
gem "capybara-webkit", github: "thoughtbot/capybara-webkit", branch: "1.0"
```